# ColdFusion submitting a form

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a form where an user can add new people to the list. I need it to only allow the form to update if the required fields are filled out.

My current code works in Chrome or FireFox, but not with with Safari. In Chrome and FireFox, it will not submit the form unless the fields are filled out. However, Safari allows the user to submit the form even if it is left blank.

Is there any other way to write the code to make it work with all three browsers? Below is just a little of the code for some of the required fields.

```
 <cfform method="post" action="##" name="aForm" id="addClientForm" class="">
 <input type="hidden" name="method" value="clientAdd">
 <input type="hidden" name="datasource" value="<cfoutput>#request.dsn#</cfoutput>">
 <input type="hidden" name="Active" value="1">

 <div style="float:left;" class="formContent470">
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <th colspan="" style="text-align:left;">Add Client</th>
</tr>
<tr><cfoutput>
    <td>
        Contact
        <span style="color:red">*</span>
        <input type="Text" name="Contact" value="" required="Yes" message="Contact      is required" maxLength="75" class="inputText430"> 
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Client Name
        <span style="color:red">*</span>
        <input type="Text" name="ClientName" value="" required="Yes" message="Client Name is required" maxlength="75" class="inputText430">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
```

Comment: warning: You don't want to push the `request.DSN` over the link. You are also missing a lot of your code. Last but not least, `action="##"` needs to be replaced with something that will respond to the form when it is submitted

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to use cfform and cfinput.

Comment: if i change <input type="Text" name="Contact" value="" required="Yes" message="Contact is required" maxLength="75" class="inputText430"> to <cfinput type="Text" name="Contact" value="" required="Yes" message="Contact is required" maxLength="75" class="inputText430"> than whenever I submit the form it will let me without any of the fields filled out on all the different web browsers

Comment: Please do not use `cfform` and `cfinoput` - and shame on you Dan for suggesting as much. Use a client side validation library, or use ValidateThis which will do client side AND server side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for server side validation. I would, of course, validate client side using Javascript and THEN back that up with server side.

Despite the well meaning advice avoid CFINPUT and CFFORM if you can (My opinion others may differ). You'll gain far greater flexibility/portability using a client side library like JQuery and sticking with plain Jane HTML form fields (steps off podium).

That being said, and assuming you'll stick with server side validation as a starting point, there's an "old school" CF method of form validation using hidden fields with specially formed name attributes. That should solve your problem. You can see this method described very well in [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a7b.html).

-Cheers!